# Puppet install java and then find JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, puppet

I am using the puppetlabs-java module to install Java. I then need to use the environment variable JAVA_HOME once this is done in other steps.

How could this be achieved? It appears the module does not provide the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Search in its Github repository [puppetlabs/java](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-java)

the JAVA_HOME setting is in [manifests/params.pp](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-java/blob/dcc2867152b29c9026fa4588e985ae2415951f25/manifests/params.pp)

You will see the key=>value for java_home, such as

```
          'java_home'        => "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-${::architecture}/",
```

or

```
          'java_home'        => '/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/',
```

You can re-use it in puppet code by

```
$java_home                = $java::params::java[$distribution]['java_home']
```

Take a look on its [manifests/init.pp](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-java/blob/7224baa72ded1571ebead8219a689f840ca4e607/manifests/init.pp) , you should be fine to understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Check local persistence for the OS - in Windows, you'll find the path in:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\
   CurrentVersion, then use that to access the JavaHome key.
```

It's not typical of a Java install to set JAVA_HOME, but it's typical for applications to try to use it.  It's a strange discrepancy.

Comment: "Applications" is a big word, its a legacy trait from the days where there wasn't a guarantee of a "default Java" being provided by the operating system (most notably Windows flavors); as such shell scripts and installation scripts expected the environmental variable to exist to be able to have some certainty of not only working but also picking the right Java installation.

Comment: Kieveli what about a Unix setup?

Comment: You should be able to use the java.util.Preferences API to access the values stored in local OS persistence.  I haven't done this, but it's likely the way to go.

Comment: In linux, I'm not really sure... I was just hoping I could point you in somewhat of the right direction.